# How to delete rows if it does not satisfy a condition using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
ID  Days TreatmentGiven TreatmentNumber
--- ---- -------------- ---------------
1    0      False             NaN
1    30     False             NaN
1    40     True              1.0
1    56     True              2.0 
2    0      False             NaN
2    14     True              4.0
2    28     True              5.0
3    0      False             NaN
3    28     True              1.0
3    56     True              2.0
4    0      False             NaN
4    100    True              6.0
4    128    True              7.0
```

I'd like to delete all rows for an ID where an ID does not have a TreatmentNumber == 1.0, so that the result is the following:

```
ID  Days TreatmentGiven TreatmentNumber
--- ---- -------------- ---------------
1    0      False             NaN
1    30     False             NaN
1    40     True              1.0
1    56     True              2.0 
3    0      False             NaN
3    28     True              1.0
3    56     True              2.0
```

What is the best way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do with `groupby().transform()`:

```
df[df.TreatmentNumber.eq(1).groupby(df['ID']).transform('any')]
```

Output:

```
   ID  Days  TreatmentGiven  TreatmentNumber
0   1     0           False              NaN
1   1    30           False              NaN
2   1    40            True              1.0
3   1    56            True              2.0
7   3     0           False              NaN
8   3    28            True              1.0
9   3    56            True              2.0
```

Answer (score 2):

#### `groupby` and `filter`

```
df.groupby('ID').filter(lambda d: d.TreatmentNumber.eq(1).any())

   ID  Days  TreatmentGiven  TreatmentNumber
0   1     0           False              NaN
1   1    30           False              NaN
2   1    40            True              1.0
3   1    56            True              2.0
7   3     0           False              NaN
8   3    28            True              1.0
9   3    56            True              2.0
```

Comment: I grew accustomed to `transform` so that I forgot all about `filter`.

Comment: `transform` is quicker (at least in naive testing).  I'm just trying to add marginal value (-:

Answer (score 0):

we can use `isin` and a boolean to find your ids

```
ids = df.loc[df['TreatmentNumber'].eq(1)]['ID'].unique()

df1 = df.loc[df['ID'].isin(ids)]

print(df1)


   ID  Days  TreatmentGiven  TreatmentNumber
0   1     0           False              NaN
1   1    30           False              NaN
2   1    40            True              1.0
3   1    56            True              2.0
7   3     0           False              NaN
8   3    28            True              1.0
9   3    56            True              2.0
```